# ODI-1228: Task fails on the target ORACLE connection . Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

Im tring to run an interface in ODI. I get this error that table or view doesn't exist, while i already have the views and tables associated to the user .

Im using Oracle12c database and ODI11g .

Can you please help me what should i check in order to make this code run ?

> this is the code of the job

```
insert /*+#GDWH2MYGDWH.PRM_INSERT_HINT*/ into   "GDWH2MYGDWH ".TRG_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB  
( 

BATCH_NUMBER,
EXTERNAL_BATCH_NUMBER,
JOBGROUP_ID,
JOB_ID,
RUNTIME_STATUS,
STARTED,
FINISHED,
ODI_SESS_NAME,
HISTORY_INDICATOR,
RECORD_CREATE_DATE,
HISTORY_NO,
RETRY_NO 

)

select /*+#GDWH2MYGDWH.PRM_SELECT_HINT*/ 

VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.BATCH_NUMBER as BATCH_NUMBER,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.EXTERNAL_BATCH_NUMBER as EXTERNAL_BATCH_NUMBER,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.JOBGROUP_ID as JOBGROUP_ID,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.JOB_ID as JOB_ID,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.RUNTIME_STATUS as RUNTIME_STATUS,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.STARTED as STARTED,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.FINISHED as FINISHED,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.ODI_SESS_NAME as ODI_SESS_NAME,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.HISTORY_INDICATOR as HISTORY_INDICATOR,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.RECORD_CREATE_DATE as RECORD_CREATE_DATE,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.HISTORY_NO as HISTORY_NO,
VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB.RETRY_NO as RETRY_NO

   from "GDWH2MYGDWH ".VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB   VW_ODI_JC_RUNTIME_JOB 
where (1=1)
```

> Error at Command Line:40 Column:28
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: "GDWH2MYGDWH ": Do you really have a trailing space in your schema name?

Comment: You can also check if the user, which ODI connects to database, have the required permission to read table. But it is better to check, what @HoneyBadger has said, first.

Comment: Thank you @HoneyBadger ,that space was the one that was causing the error.. Sometimes we are stuck in such simple errors .